# Laravel methodNotAllowed on post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm not sure why it's not working...

I'm trying to update a user and I keep getting method not allowed error exception.

-- routes

```
Route::get('superadmin/users', ['as' => 'superadmin.users', 'uses' => 'SuperAdminController@usersIndex']);
Route::post('superadmin/users/{id}', ['as' => 'superadmin.editUser', 'uses' => 'SuperAdminController@editUser']);
```

-- controller

```
public function usersIndex()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return View::make('superadmin.users',compact('users'));
}

public function editUser($id)
{
   $user = User::findOrFail($id);
   $user->email = Input::get('email');
   $user->save();
   return Redirect::route('superadmin.users')->with('alertsuccess', 'User has been updated.');
}
```

-- view

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['superadmin.editUser', $user->id], 'class' => 'form']) }}
   <div class="form-group">
       {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:', ['class' => 'placeholder-hidden']) }}
       {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email'), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
   </div>
   {{ Form::submit('Update User', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Trying this `$user = User::find($id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably as you need to set up a resource controller in order to use the PATCH method. Try using POST instead.